# Show some divs when others are hidden with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want, when a CATEGORY is active, for the `.closeorshow` div to be hidden. If no category is selected, the `.closeorshow` div should be shown.

I tested a bit with `$(".closeorshow").hide()` and `.show()`, but I am a jQuery beginner and I couldn't figure it out. The problem seems to be that the `.closeorshow` div reappears whenever I unselect any category, instead of when no categories are selected.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGwpn/3/).

HTML:

```
<ul class="types">
    <li class="item" data-target="games">Games</li>
    <li class="item" data-target="music">Music</li>
    <li class="item" data-target="movies">Movies</li>
    <li class="item" data-target="ljudobild">Ljud & Bild</li>
</ul>
<div class="description" id="games">Description of Games</div>
<div class="description" id="music">Description of Music</div>
<div class="description" id="movies">Description of Movies</div>
<div class="description" id="ljudobild">Description of Television</div>

<br><br>

    <div class="closeorshow">
        This class are going to be SHOWN when NONE of the items are selected, and HIDED
        when one of the items is selected.
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.types li').click( function(t) {
        $('.closeorshow').hide();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');$(this).addClass('item');
        $('.closeorshow').show();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');$(this).removeClass('item');
    }
        $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to check whether the class `.active` exists. This is done by calling `$(".active")`, which will produce an array, meaning it has access to the `.length` method. If the `length` of the array is greater than 0, you don't want to show `.closeorshow`, so call `$(".closeorshow").hide()`. Otherwise, you do want it shown, so call `$("#.closeorshow").show()`.

Tell me if everything isn't bueno.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/yGwpn/5/)

I only changed your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.types li').on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active item");
        $('#' + $(this).attr("data-target")).toggle();

        if ($(".active").length === 0)
            $(".closeorshow").show();
        else
            $(".closeorshow").hide();

    });
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/kpQN4/1/) made originally to demonstrate the same concept. Only keeping for reference since it's simpler than your problem, but nevertheless demonstrates how to fix the problem in question.

Comment: Well, to be honest, i don't understand much of that.. As i mentioned i'm totally new to jQuery, and this was like "what?!" to me :( Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Nonez I'll do it with your fiddle. Hold up.

Comment: @Nonez I reworked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/yGwpn/5/) and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping me, i appreciate it! Thank you!